# Erro ao fechar o navegador no selenium-webdriver

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Código:

```
firefoxbin = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'drivers', 'geckodriver'))

assert os.path.isfile(firefoxbin), "Driver \"{}\" não disponível.".format(firefoxbin)
        logger.debug(f"firefoxbin: {type(firefoxbin)}")
        navegador = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=firefoxbin)
        logger.debug(f"navegador: {type(navegador)}")
        navegador.get('https://pt.stackoverflow.com/')
finally:
    navegador.close()
```

Error:

> Exception: 'str' object has no attribute 'close'

Comment: Cadê o `try` desse `finally`?

Comment: Esqueci de colocar na pergunta, mas no código está certo. Descobri o erro e logo posto. Mas resumindo era basicamente desabilitar o marionette.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No linux a execução ocorre carretamento, no windows a compatibilidade do marionette não então foi preciso mudar o padrão do capabilities desabilitando o marionette.

Resposta:

```
firefoxbin = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'drivers', 'geckodriver'))

assert os.path.isfile(firefoxbin), "Driver \"{}\" não disponível.".format(firefoxbin)
        logger.debug(f"firefoxbin: {type(firefoxbin)}")

        cap = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
        cap["marionette"] = False
        navegador = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=cap, executable_path=firefoxbin)

        logger.debug(f"navegador: {type(navegador)}")
        navegador.get('https://pt.stackoverflow.com/')
finally:
    navegador.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema aqui é que o seu código `finally` vai rodar não importa o que aconteça anteriormente. 
Seria importante olhar em detalhes o output do seu código para entender melhor o que está acontecendo.

Mas um problema claro é que você fez a criação do `webdriver` (variável `navegador`) e não checou se ela efetivamente resultou em um objeto `Webdriver`.

Como o output não foi esse objeto, então, o erro diz que a `string` retornada pela chamada não possui um método `close()`, que no caso pertence ao `webdriver`.

Para testar, antes do `finally`, adicione `print navegador` e veja o retorno. Caso a criação tenha tido sucesso, você terá um retorno como esse:

```
<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver.WebDriver (session="49785161406c39caa34c0ae34c90a17b")>
```

Caso contrário, veja se o caminho que está usando realmente possui o driver `geckodriver`, se o `get` não está retornando algum erro, ou outros problemas com a criação / uso do `navegador` antes de chegar no `finally`.